# Page Edit - Re-arange the order of contents (images, banners, blocks) on a wordpress website

Tags: editor

i'm using my company's website's (https://www.generationhope.ph/shop-hope/)- wp-admin - to configure the change as given in the image as attached.

ie. rearrange the contents, move Education section below Environment section.

To do this - I go to Page-editor - and I don't see anything there except the header - "Where would you like to make a difference today?"

I also tried - going to smart blocks to get some clue to move the smart boxes (with purchase options) up and down but to no avail.

im fairly new to this and super confused on how to do this. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This all looks as though it's hard coded into the template. The user put multiple sections on the shop page and then built custom metaboxes in the back-end to populate info.  It's not using the Block Editor, it's using TinyMCE `wp_editor` instances.
The good news is that re-arranging it should just mean swapping around sections in a template file.  (Hard to help without seeing the template code.)  To the right hand side you should see that there is a template assigned to the page, hopefully. Find that template via FTP in the theme directory and add it's code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is page is an archive that is generated by querying WordPress for all posts that are of the 'Product' post type. If you want to modify the position of the products on this page, try to modify the publish date for each of the products.